# CakePHP app 404s when going to URL subdirectories

Tags: php, nginx, cakephp, debian

I recently imported a CakePHP project to a new server and am able to load the webroot e.g. example.com however when I go to example.com/pages/about or example.com/pages/contact I get a 404. I'm using Nginx, which I assume isn't configured correctly because the same CakePHP project is deployed on a different server. (I don't have a great understanding about CakePHP but have used similar PHP MVC frameworks e.g. Laravel)

```html
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /home/me/directory/webroot;
        autoindex off;
        index index.php;

        server_name _;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

I'm wondering what isn't configured correctly that causes any non-root-uris to 404.

Comment: Have you had a look at [**the sample configuration**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#nginx) in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment to my question, changing

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

...to...

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

...did the trick.